# What does package:mine mean in Android Studio Logcat?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I can see `package:mine` prefilled in the Android Studio's Log cat filter. Can someone explain what it means?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Logcat queries with `package:<package-ID>` filters logs for a specific package identifier, also the `mine` keyword in this refers to the local app projects identifier. Thus all logs for your local app can be shown.

Read more about this [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#logcat-search)